# pandas - replace values with percent of observations that are below/less

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I have a df like this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a})
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
```

I would like to replace these values with values that shows how many of the observations are less than the value (in percents). Like this:

```
>>> df
   a  how_many_percent_of_observations_are_less_than_value_from_a
0  1  0 (no observations that are lower, 0/8)
1  2  .125 (one observation is lower, 1/8)
2  3  .25 (two observations are lower, 2/8)
3  4  
4  5  
5  6  
6  7  
7  8  .875 (7 observations are lower, 7/8)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy broadcasting for test if `a` values are less like same values, then count for number of `True`s per `'columns'` and divide by length of array:

```
a = df.a.to_numpy()

print (a[:, None] < a)
[[False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False  True  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False False  True  True]
 [False False False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False False False False]]


df['new'] = (a[:, None] < a).sum(axis=0) / len(a)
print (df)
   a    new
0  1  0.000
1  2  0.125
2  3  0.250
3  4  0.375
4  5  0.500
5  6  0.625
6  7  0.750
7  8  0.875
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. It is my fault, I've asked the question wrong. I have edited it now.

Comment: @777moneymaker - I edited answer for test less values

Comment: @Ch3steR - I think not, because here are tested values of `a` column. Because consecutive like index your solution got same ouput, although not tested `a` values

Comment: @Ch3steR - Super, one thing `np.searchsorted` working well for any data? Not 100% sure, but seems need sorted (like in question).

Comment: @Ch3steR - yes, agree. So you use random values for test? For are generated?

Answer (score 5):

Using `rank`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a})

ranks = df['a'].rank(method = 'min')
maxi = ranks.size
df['b'] = (ranks-1)/maxi
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   a      b
0  1  0.000
1  2  0.125
2  3  0.250
3  4  0.375
4  5  0.500
5  6  0.625
6  7  0.750
7  8  0.875
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work when data is shuffled. I posted timeits and benchmarking setup. Please check.

Comment: Hi @Ch3steR when I was writing this answer I did think about which method to use for `rank`. But then I went with the default (max).

Comment: Edited my answer to add method as min, should work now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with [`ndarray.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) here.

```
a = df.a.to_numpy()
idx = a.argsort()
df['new'] = np.searchsorted(a[idx], a) / len(df)
df
   a    new
0  1  0.000
1  2  0.125
2  3  0.250
3  4  0.375
4  5  0.500
5  6  0.625
6  7  0.750
7  8  0.875
```

---

**Timeit analysis:**

Benchmarking setup

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
a = a.repeat(1_000_000)
np.random.shuffle(a)
a = a[:1_000_000]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a})
```

---

**Results:**

```
In [69]: %%timeit 
    ...: a = df.a.to_numpy() 
    ...: (a[:, None] < a).sum(axis=0) / len(a) 
    ...:  
    ...:  
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 931. GiB for an array with shape (1000000, 1000000) and data type bool

In [70]: %%timeit 
    ...: a = df.a.to_numpy() 
    ...: idx = a.argsort() 
    ...: np.searchsorted(a[idx], a) / len(df) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
96 ms ± 1.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [71]: %%timeit 
    ...: ranks = df['a'].rank() 
    ...: maxi = ranks.max() 
    ...: (ranks-1)/maxi 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
86 ms ± 1.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

For small data, benchmarking setup

```
a = a[:10_000]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a})
```

---

**Results:**

```
In [73]: %%timeit 
    ...: ranks = df['a'].rank() 
    ...: maxi = ranks.max() 
    ...: (ranks-1)/maxi 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
1.29 ms ± 205 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [74]: %%timeit 
    ...: a = df.a.to_numpy() 
    ...: idx = a.argsort() 
    ...: np.searchsorted(a[idx], a) / len(df) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
684 µs ± 19.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [75]: %%timeit 
    ...: a = df.a.to_numpy() 
    ...: (a[:, None] < a).sum(axis=0) / len(a) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
122 ms ± 2.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**Equality check**

```
ranks = df['a'].rank()
maxi = ranks.max()
ris = ((ranks-1)/maxi).to_numpy() 

jez = (a[:, None] < a).sum(axis=0) / len(a) 
idx = a.argsort()
ch3 = np.searchsorted(a[idx], a) / len(df)

(jez == ch3).all()
# True
(jez == ris).all()
# False
```

Comment: Also tested if same ouput?

Comment: also missing shuffle ;)

Comment: And for test `np.all(ch3 == jez)` ;)

Comment: hmmm, I guess if use after then performance shouldbe different (only guess)

Comment: I dont see it, becuse scroller bar

Comment: You can test it in your data, if same or similr timeings not necessary